# Is it possible to connect to an SMB server without a VPN

Tags: networking, file-sharing, smb

This is something i've been struggling with recently, and after the number of other stack overflow and super user questions i've gone through, most people turn to a vpn. what i want to know is: is it possible to connect to an SMB server from an external network (hosted using windows sharing) without using any other software besides windows. i tried port forwarding, disabling firewalls, loose permissions, but to no avail.

Furthermore, would a setup like this be possible if i were running something like samba on linux?

Comment: Your router usually is using private IP address scheme,  which will not route traffic to internet http://superuser.com/questions/324815/networking-and-routing-of-private-ip-ranges

Comment: @Bilo I'm sorry, i don't quite follow

Comment: Please refer to the reference post (just updated :) ) for details

Comment: That makes sense, but isnt that the reason behind port forwarding: to bring a local resource, say an http server, to the router and be sent out on behalf of the router?

Comment: If you have the Enterprise edition of the Windows clients, you can use DirectAccess: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn636118.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running a packet sniffer (e.g. Wireshark) on the server side connected directly to your modem (without the router)? Try performing some packet sniffing if you have not.

Many ISP's drop packets directed at ports 137, 138, 139, 445, and a few others, coming into their networks in an effort to 'secure' their customers (and their investment). If Windows file sharing over the Internet still does not work after you port-forward said ports, this is probably the cause. There is nothing you can do about it and you will have to resort to FTP, SSH, or some other means.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. slightly unfortunate. only reason i wanted to use smb is because windows supports it so natively as opposed to ftp. i'll do some packet sniffing though later on today to see if this is the issue at hand. thank you!

Comment: so i did some wiresharking, and it looks like my ISP is in fact blocking those ports. thanks so much!